# How do you get WebGL to support gpu resident code?

Tags: browser, webgl, opencl, gpgpu

My goal is to implement a language interpreter to stay resident in the gpgpu to which I will send data and language snippets, and have all operations performed without communicating with the cpu.  I will need to know the gpu-side index of the client code so each instance can use its identity to make decisions.

In the past, I wrote a gpu resident RPN language interpreter using OpenCL and/or CUDA from Python (https://github.com/jlettvin/rpna) and I wrote another in C, but I have been unable to identify documentation or example code to show how to do this in WebGL.  It may be that WebGL simply doesn't support it.  If that is true, I may abandon it for this project.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: WebGL is just [OpenGL ES 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.pdf) offered securely in the browser. WebGL2 is just [OpenGL ES 3.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf).  That's it. If you can do your thing with either of those APIs then you're good to go. [There are plenty of GPGPU projects](http://www.vizitsolutions.com/portfolio/webgl/gpgpu/) that [run within the limits](http://gpu.rocks/) of WebGL/OpenGL ES 2.0/OpenGL ES 3.0. OpenCL and CUDA are not available in the browser as of 2018-August